# CSS / Style woo commerce additional fields on checkout page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've added some code parts for checkout calculations on functions.php. After i added those codes they preview without styles. Anyone can guide me to style those results on checkout page and cart page.

I added these fields: Administration fees, Total weight, Domestic Shipping

For your reference i have attached a checkout page screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to enqueue style sheets for checkout and cart page. Please check [here](https://gist.github.com/DevinWalker/7621777)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: i add this code to functions.php but theres no any changes. can you explain more about this.